# How to use filter with same column name in different data source in tableau

Tags: mysql

The same column has different data in different data sources. I have campaign named column in first data source and the same in another data source. I want to use Campaign as a common filter in the dashboard. The problem is I cannot use the filter from one source only which excludes the another table data in filter. Anyone with any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

To filter multiple data sources with one data source, you need to ensure blend relationships are setup for the data sources you're wanting to work together. You'd want to choose the common ID (in this case that may be Campaign). You can find Edit Blend Relationships in the top left corner of Tableau, under Data in the Sheet view.

When you're creating sheets for your dashboard, make sure the link icon is red and without the slash through the icon (make sure there is a link between the data sources) on all data sources you wish to link together.

If you want your filters to apply to multiple sheets, right click on the filter pill in the filters shelf and choose from the Apply to Worksheets menu.

With Tableau, there can be many ways to accomplish a similar task. If you can use your SQL query (going off the tag) to filter out the data you'll need, that is more preferable for some.